# how do I get Controller data from ModelValidatorContext in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-validation

I have a custom model validator:

```
public class MyvalidationAttribute : Attribute, IModelValidator {
    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Let's say, for the purposes of validation I need to get some data from the controller. I am not an expert in Reflection voodoo, but I can get *some* data about controller:

```
var descriptor = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
```

or

```
var typeInfo = descriptor.ControllerTypeInfo;
```

but if I have a variable in the controller, say, repository of DbContext that was passed via DI (although I doubt if it is important) - how can I access that variable from the validator?

**NOTE**: I simplified the use case for [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) purposes. I realize that this is a very brittle way to go and there are better way to do validation when all I need to do is to do remote validation. My use case is much different.

Comment: Trying to reflect a private or protected field from a controller for the purpose you call it leads you to a very very dark path, which calls for trouble (hard to maintain code, very fragile to changes). First and fore most maybe you'll get more specific on what and why do you need to get something from the controller? There may be better approaches

Comment: it doesn't have to be private/protected field. It may very well be public method `GetImportantValue()` or similar. And it doesn't have to be through reflection - the goal is to get to Controller object in *some* way. I could derive all controllers from common `AppControllerBase` and have the variable or the method in it. So, the question is narrow and technical: is it possible to get Controller object from custom model validator?